# Gradle cannot find plugin in Docker during gradle build

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, java-8

I am attempting to containerize a spring boot application that is using Gradle 6.9 and JVM 1.8. I can build on my local machine; however, when I attempt to build within the container I get this error:

`Plugin [id: 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties', version: '1.4.15'] was not found in any of the following sources: 4.220 4.220 - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace) 4.220 - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties.gradle.plugin:1.4.15') 4.220   Searched in the following repositories: 4.221     Gradle Central Plugin Repository`

Local project info:

```
Gradle 6.9
Build time:   2021-05-07 07:28:53 UTC  
Revision:     afe2e24ababc7b0213ccffff44970aa18035fc0e  
Kotlin:       1.4.20  
Groovy:       2.5.12  
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020  
JVM:          1.8.0_402 (Amazon.com Inc. 25.402-b08)  
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64
```

Container project info:

```
Gradle 6.9 
Build time:   2021-05-07 07:28:53 UTC  
Revision:     afe2e24ababc7b0213ccffff44970aa18035fc0e  
Kotlin:       1.4.20  
Groovy:       2.5.12  
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020  
JVM:          1.8.0_292 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.292-b10)  
OS:           Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 amd64
```

I attempted to use various gradle images with different jdks as well as using a jdk8 base image and manually installing Gradle.

Comment: It looks like Gradle is not able to download the JARs of the plugins. Check that you are giving your Docker container proper network access. I think this is a Docker problem and not a Gradle problem.

Comment: Try adding `--network host` do your docker run command.